# I want add this ArrayList to an existing .txt file

Tags: java

I want to know how to add this arraylist to an existing .txt file.

Person personid = new Person(title, firstName, lastName, address, emailAddress, 
        homePhone, cellPhone, status, dateOfBirth);

```
    ArrayList<String> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    personList.add(title); 
    personList.add(firstName); 
    personList.add(lastName);
    personList.add(address);
    personList.add(emailAddress);
    personList.add(cellPhone);  
    personList.add(status);
    personList.add(dateOfBirth);

    try { 
     File file = new File("memberlog.txt");
     /*If file gets created then the createNewFile() 
      * method would return true or if the file is 
      * already present it would return false
      */
         boolean fvar = file.createNewFile();
     if (fvar){
          System.out.println("File has been created successfully");
     }
    else{
           System.out.println("File already present at the specified 
    location");
     }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Occurred:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried something. SO guys are not going to write code for you

Comment: I have only been able to create the txt file...

Comment: I have been checking the website and there have been no answers that explains how to get the arraylist written in a file.

Comment: you can use file writer to write data into file in java https://www.javatpoint.com/java-filewriter-class

Comment: I used this code...it only worked when i used a string...when I added the personList it did not run.

Comment: see my answer. you have to loop throw your array list and write each string in array one by one

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        personList.add(title);
        personList.add(firstName);
        personList.add(lastName);
        personList.add(address);
        personList.add(emailAddress);
        personList.add(cellPhone);
        personList.add(status);
        personList.add(dateOfBirth);

        try {
            File file = new File("memberlog.txt");

            boolean fvar = file.createNewFile();
            if (fvar) {
                System.out.println("File has been created successfully");
                //Create a file writer
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("memberlog.txt");// should have fill path as parameter
                //loop throw your array list
                for (String item : personList) {
                    //write each string to your file line by line
                    fw.write(item);
                }
                //close the file writer
                fw.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("File already present at the specified location");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occurred:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<String> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    personList.add("hai");
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("D:\\cicd poc\\abc.txt"));
    for (String s : personList) {
        printWriter.println(s);
    }
    printWriter.close();
}
```

If you want to append to the file use this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    personList.add("appending and writing");
    personList.add("line by line");
    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\cicd poc\\abc.txt", true));
    for (String s : personList) {
        output.append(s + "\n");
    }
    output.close();
}
```

Comment: I do not understand why this code is not working....I created a txt..i saw when it was created ...but this code is not submitting the arraylist to the file. I am using cloud9 ide.

Comment: I have updated the code. This one i tried in my eclipse IDE and is working.

Comment: This works perfectly...can you direct me to any resources you used...I need to learn how to append the now....I trying to create a database with persons personal information.

Comment: updated the code in my answer. See whether this is the one you are looking.

Comment: thank you very much..I learnt so much...hopefully I will get better so I can help others.

Answer (score 0):

### **try with this code**

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    ArrayList<String> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    personList.add("title");
    personList.add("firstName");
    personList.add("lastName");
    personList.add("address");
    personList.add("emailAddress");
    personList.add("cellPhone");
    personList.add("status");
    personList.add("dateOfBirth");


        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("memberlog.txt"))
        {
              ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

              oos.writeObject(personList);
        }


     catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Occurred:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

Comment: I added this code to my main class and it didn't execute. there were errors.

Comment: check this example https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/objectinputstream/java-objectinputstream-and-objectoutputstream-example/

Comment: thank you but I'm trying to add an arraylist to a txt file, not strings.

Comment: try this code this is for storing entire object of arraylist

Comment: thank you very much but I'm getting an error in my txt file ���������� like this

Comment: you said u want to store arraylist in file so it will storing arraylist which is not readable in file u need to retrieve that object and print then u will get text

Comment: I understand what you mean...I didnt think about it like that..thank you

Answer (score 0):

First import java.io.*;

Then create FileWriter object inside parentheses where you checked if the file is present :-

```
FileWriter fout=new FileWriter(“memberlog.txt”);
```

Now use the reference to write in file by using write() method.

But since you already created an array list with all the data use for loop to take data from each index inside the ArrayList.

I am using advance for loop-

```
for(String s: personList)
{
 fout.write(s);
}
```

Now for no further problems during the writing of all data

fout.flush();  and fout.close(); in end.

Comment: Thank you very much..someone suggest this exact method and it worked effeciently.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) can help you to do this.
If you want to write line by line:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
...
String separator = System.lineSeparator();
for (String person : personList) {
   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, person + separator, true)
}
```

Or may be it's will be better for you to concatenate all persons to one big String first and then write it to file:

```
String separator = System.lineSeparator();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String person : personList) {
   sb.append(person).append(separator);
}
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, sb.toString());
```